# A lot of Warnings when importing tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed TensorFlow (by creating an environment on Conda and then installing tensor flow on it using this tutorial video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujTCoH21GlA&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-mP7qA9cagf68V06sko5otr&index=1)

but when I run the simple code:

```
     import tensorflow
```

it returns a lot of warnings like this:

```
    C:\Users\safa\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

However, the process finishes with exit code 0. What are these warning for?

Answer (score 4):

I think since the Python=3.6 is the latest python version which supports TensorFlow, and the newest version of NumPy for Python 3.6 is NumPy 1.16.4; I had to downgrade my NumPy package from 1.17 to 1.16.4 to solve this problem. The warnings disappeared after doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Deprecated means that the function is going to be removed in the future version. Basically the warning is for the tensorflow itself from numpy since tensorflow uses a deprecated function from numpy.

```
Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,))
```

And tensorflow uses (type,1) in

```
'(1,)type'.np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

It's actually not a problem for you but if you are concerned about it maybe try to update tensorflow to the newest version.

Comment: But my TensorFlow version is 1.14.0 which is the latest.